Azure data factory edit data flow button does not work?
In Azure data factory -> Pipelines -> Move and transform -> Data flow task, I'm familiar with the "Edit data flow" button below to configure data flow tasks. But that does not work anymore.
Is this a bug? or are there any other alternative ways to add dataflows to the pipeline without using the command line?


Only when dataflow name is added in settings, edit dataflow button will work. Without any dataflow, it will not open the dataflow.


In above gif, edit dataflow is clicked without adding the dataflow. No dataflow is opened.

When dataflow is added and then edit dataflow is clicked, it works.



Thanks, it worked I think I forgot to add dataflow. I thought in earlier days it was working even without adding a dataflow. Anyway thanks now clarified

Great to know it helped you
